# Find $n$ such that the congruence $x^n\equiv 2\mod 13$ has a solution for $x$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Find $n$ such that the congruence $x^n\equiv 2\mod 13$ has a solution for $x$.

I am not getting any idea how to start this problem. Please give some hits

Comment: Already $n=1$ will do. Or do you want to find *all* $n$ ? $n=0$ has no solution.

Comment: Suppose you have an $n$ greater than $12$. Do you see how you can use Fermat's little theorem to reduce it to an $n'$ smaller than $12$? And if you start with such an $n'$, do you see how to make it into a larger $n$? Then it boils down to finding the solutions for $1 \leq n \leq 13$.

Answer (score 0):

Select $n=11$, then we have: $x^{11} \equiv 2 \pmod{13} \iff 1 \equiv x^{12} \equiv 2x \pmod{13}$. Obviously as $(13,2)=1$ this equation has solution, namely numbers of the type $x=13k+7$.

Furthermore since $13$ is a prime using the Fermat's Little Theorem it's enough to check the cases $n\le 11$. Now use that $2$ isn't a quadratic residue modulo $13$, coming from Legendre Symbol. So you're now left with odd numbers less than or equal to $13$.

$n=1$ obviously is a solution, but that's too trivial

Comment: How do you select $n=11 $ you have to find all n and prove that a solution exists

Comment: @learnmore You are asking for $n$ such that the equation has a solution, not all solution, according to your questions. Anyway it's easy to notice that 2 is neither quadratic nor cubic residue modulo 13. Now using this and the Fermat's Little Theorem it's enough to check the numbers less than 13 and not divisible by $3$ or $2$. You have just 4 possibilities and I check 2 of them. 

At the end all $n$ are of the form $\{12k+1, 12k+5, 12k+7, 12k+11\}$ for some non-negative integer $k$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the question is to find all positive integers $n$ such that $x^n-2$ has a root in the field $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. One checks that this is exactly the case for $n=1,5,7,11$, where we can assume that $n\le 11$. The Berlekamp algorithm easily shows the existence (or non-existence) of a linear factor; e.g., $x^{11}-2$ has the linear factor $(x+6)$.

Comment: I don't get how you say $n=1,5,7,11$ are the solutions ;even if you claim so you will have to check $x^5\equiv 2$ for all x<13 which is quite time consuming and not an efficient way to solve

Comment: $x^5-2=(x^4 + 6x^3 + 10x^2 + 8x + 9)(x + 7)$, by the Berlekamp algorithm. Of course, there are quicker ways to see that $-7=6$ is a root.